# How to modify text content with some altered pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to copy a line of text from source to destination and whereever a specific pattern is encountered I need to make some modification to it.

Input:

```
I am #check Some Text/#Middle#check Text/#
```

Expected output:

```
#check Some Text is manipulated/#Middle#check Text/#
```

Actual output:

```
#check Some Text is manipulated/##check Text/#
```

---

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#check)([^/>]*)(/#)");
String line = "I am #check Some Text/#Middle#check Text/#";
String replaced = "";               
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while(matcher.find())
{
    if(matcher.group(2).contains("Some"))
        replaced+=matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2)+" is manipulated"+matcher.group(3);
    else 
        replaced+=matcher.group();
}
```

Any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend using [`Matcher.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) instead of building the string yourself. The complete all matches of the pattern are replaced with the given replacement String. You can use the capturing groups from your pattern by using `$X` (e.g. `$1` for the first group) in your replacement String.

So your code would look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.+?(?=#)(.*)(#check[^/#]+Some[^/#]+)(/#)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
String replaced = matcher.replaceAll("$1$2 is manipulated$3$4");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Here are some results for given inputs:

```
IN:  I am #check Some Text/#Middle#check Text/#
OUT: #check Some Text is manipulated/#Middle#check Text/#4

IN:  I am #check hello there Some Text/#Middle#check Text/#
OUT: #check hello there Some Text is manipulated/#Middle#check Text/#

IN:  I am #check Text/#Middle#check Some Text/#
OUT: #check Text/#Middle#check Some Text is manipulated/#
```

If the pattern should match case insensitive you can use this to create it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: My problem is "some" can appear anywhere it's not mandatory to appear on the beganing only.

The input may be  --->>>>

I am #check hello there Some Text/#Middle#check Text/#

that's why  i used line.contains() method

Comment: @Anand I updated my answer. Hope it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a pattern like `(.*)(\/}.*\/})`, match until the first `/}` to get what's before, and what's after

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(\\/}.*\\/})");
String line = "I am {check Some Text/}Middle{check Text/}";
String replaced;               
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if(matcher.find()) {
    replaced = matcher.group(1)+" is manipulated"+matcher.group(2);
}else{ 
    replaced = matcher.group();
}
System.out.println(replaced)
```

>[`Code demo`](https://ideone.com/yUXoBG)

Comment: your logic will fail if the input is 

I am {check Text/}Middle{check Some Text/}

Comment: @Anand you changed the expected output after I answered, i couldn't write somethong good for the problem^^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regexes and `Matcher`s, you can make use of `Matcher`'s `replaceAll()` method. Basically, [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) replaces the matched text in its `Matcher` and replaces it with whatever is in the string passed to `replaceAll(str)`. For example, you could use:

```
matcher.replaceAll("$1$2 is manipulated$3")
```

instead of your entire `if`/`else` block above.